# Left join in Opaleye

Tags: haskell, opaleye

I have been trying to run a left join using Opaleye in a project but I'm not being able to make the code compile. I start with two "models" which represent tables that are associated:

First:

```
data ModelA' a b = Model { primA :: a, foreignA :: b }
type ModelA = ModelA' UUID UUID
type ModelAColumn = ModelA' (Column PGUuid) (Column (Nullable PGUuid))

$(makeAdaptorAndInstance "pModelA" ''ModelA')

table :: Table ModelAColumn ModelAColumn
table = Opaleye.table "model_a" $ pModelA (ModelA (tableColumn "uuid") (tableColumn "foreign"))
```

And also:

```
data ModelB' a b = Model { primB :: a, valB :: b }
type ModelB = ModelB' UUID String
type ModelBColumn = ModelB' (Column PGUuid) (Column PGText)

$(makeAdaptorAndInstance "pModelB" ''ModelB')

table :: Table ModelBColumn ModelBColumn
table = Opaleye.table "model_b" $ pModelB (ModelB (tableColumn "uuid") (tableColumn "val"))
```

As the types reflect, **ModelA** can have no **ModelB** associated.

I need a query to obtain pairs of **(ModelA, Maybe ModelB)** given by the left join between the tables on foreignA == primB. I was expecting it to look like:

```
doJoin :: Connection -> IO [(ModelA, Maybe ModelB)]
doJoin conn = runQuery conn query
  where
    query :: Query (ModelAColumn, Maybe ModelBColumn)
    query = leftJoin (queryTable ModelA.table) (queryTable ModelB.table) (\(ma, mb) -> foreignA ma .== primB mb)
```

But this does not work. I've also tried multiple variants, in particular I replaced the type signature in query to explicitly state the nullability of the columns at the right:

```
query :: Query (ModelAColumn, (Column (Nullable PGUuid), Column (Nullable PGText))
```

But this fails with:

> No instance for Data.Profunctor.Product.Default.Class.Default
>   Opaleye.Internal.Join.NullMaker ModelBColumn (Column (Nullable
>   PGUuid), Column (Nullable PGText).

How can I make this query in Opaleye?

Comment: Do you need to use the `Join` module over the `FunctionalJoin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of misunderstandings here.  I produced a full working version below.

Firstly, the return type of the `leftJoin` is not

```
Query (ModelAColumn, Maybe ModelBColumn)
```

You have to do

```
type ModelBNullableColumn = ModelB' (Column (Nullable PGUuid))
                                    (Column (Nullable PGText))
```

and then use

```
Query (ModelAColumn, ModelBNullableColumn)
```

Secondly, the return type of the `runQuery` is not

```
IO [(ModelA, Maybe ModelB)]
```

You have to do

```
type ModelBMaybe = ModelB' (Maybe UUID) (Maybe String)
```

and use

```
IO [(ModelA, ModelBMaybe)]
```

The reason for these differences is that `Nullable` and `Maybe` must be applied directly to every column and value in the `ModelBColumn` and `ModelB` not to the values as a whole.

(There are also some weird syntax errors like

```
ModelA { tableColumn "uuid", tableColumn "foreign" }
```

which means your code has no hope of compiling.  I fixed those, too.)

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

import           Opaleye hiding (table)
import qualified Opaleye
import Data.Profunctor.Product.TH
import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple hiding (Query)
import Data.UUID

data ModelA' a b = ModelA { primA :: a, foreignA :: b }
type ModelA = ModelA' UUID (Maybe UUID)
type ModelAColumn = ModelA' (Column PGUuid) (Column (Nullable PGUuid))

$(makeAdaptorAndInstance "pModelA" ''ModelA')

modelAtable :: Table ModelAColumn ModelAColumn
modelAtable = Opaleye.table "model_a" $ pModelA ModelA { primA = tableColumn "uuid", foreignA = tableColumn "foreign" }

data ModelB' a b = ModelB { primB :: a, valB :: b }
type ModelB = ModelB' UUID String
type ModelBMaybe = ModelB' (Maybe UUID) (Maybe String)
type ModelBColumn = ModelB' (Column PGUuid) (Column PGText)
type ModelBNullableColumn = ModelB' (Column (Nullable PGUuid)) (Column (Nullable PGText))

$(makeAdaptorAndInstance "pModelB" ''ModelB')

modelBtable :: Table ModelBColumn ModelBColumn
modelBtable = Opaleye.table "model_b" $ pModelB ModelB { primB = tableColumn "uuid", valB = tableColumn "val" }

doJoin :: Connection -> IO [(ModelA, ModelBMaybe)]
doJoin conn = runQuery conn query
  where
    query :: Query (ModelAColumn, ModelBNullableColumn)
    query = leftJoin (queryTable modelAtable) (queryTable modelBtable) (\(ma, mb) -> matchNullable (pgBool False) (.== primB mb) (foreignA ma))

main :: IO ()
main = return ()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! And apologies for the weird syntax.

Comment: You're welcome!  I will be happy to answer any more questions you have about Opaleye.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was asked and answered a much easier way of doing left joins was introduced to Opaleye.  Check out the function called [`optional`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/opaleye-0.10.0.0/docs/Opaleye-Join.html#v:optional).

Answer (score 0):

Trying changing the following:

```
query :: Query (ModelAColumn, Maybe ModelBColumn)
```

to

```
query :: Query ((Column PGUuid) (Column (Nullable PGUuid))
               , (Column (Nullable PGUuid)) (Column (Nullable PGText)))
```

Try to get that to type-check WITHOUT calling `runQuery` on it. Once that works, come back for the rest of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `Functional Join`, specifically `leftJoinF`.

Check out this https://hackage.haskell.org/package/opaleye-0.5.4.0/docs/Opaleye-FunctionalJoin.html

You would need to provide the results of a select on your two tables as the 4th and 5th argument to it. 
An equivalent of `foreignA == primB` as the 3rd argument.

For your 2nd argument you would have to specify some default value that should be used whenever the `Maybe ModelB` being returned is a `Nothing`